# Sort an unlist() in R

Tags: r, list, sorting

I've got a list with factors in it. Now I've unlist this list and I get something like this:

```
25    19     90    2   ...  
ham  spam  spam  spam ...
```

Now I want to sort the names of this, so `"25", "19",...` But I want to keep the corresponding label. Does anybody know how to do this?

I've tried with `sort(as.numeric(names(myunlist)))` but I don't know how any further steps.

Silke

Comment: I think you're looking for `order`

Comment: Specifically: `myunlist[order(as.numeric(names(myunlist)))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `order`, not `sort` in this case as the `names` and the values are linked to one another. Something like:

```
myunlist[order(as.numeric(names(myunlist)))]
#     2     19     25     90 
#"spam" "spam"  "ham" "spam"
```